# Django migrate schema from sqlite to postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, python-3.x

I am developing a large django-based project. On my laptop I use SQLite3 as a database. I have created a lot of migrations for my models. Everything seems working.

Then I want to use PostgreSQL on the production server. I have prepared an empty database and trying to do `manage.py syncdb`. And suddenly I get an error due to not existing relation.

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: suit, messages, humanize, imagekit, staticfiles, crispy_forms, storages, django_extensions, localflavor, registration
  Apply all migrations: [here list of my apps], sites, user_auth, sessions, auth
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Creating table registration_registrationprofile
    Running deferred SQL...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "user_auth_account" does not exist
```

Trying to drop my sqlite database and perform `syncdb` with the new sqlite: it creates the schema without issues.

Here I've realized that SQLite does not use Foreign Key relations and simply uses `integer` types for all references. So it works for sqlite. Very smart, Django. But all my models are depending of each other. And I want to use different databases.

Now I have a bunch of migrations working on SQLite only.

I understand that it is possible to run migrations one-by-one for each application where the model first gets created. But it would be a hell.

Is it possible to detect dependencies and run these migrations in correct order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django handles dependencies between models in migrations correctly. What it can't handle, and what it explicitly warns against [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#dependencies), is unmigrated apps with dependencies on migrated apps:

> Be aware, however, that unmigrated apps cannot depend on migrated
>   apps, by the very nature of not having migrations. This means that it
>   is not generally possible to have an unmigrated app have a ForeignKey
>   or ManyToManyField to a migrated app; some cases may work, but it will
>   eventually fail.
>
> > **Warning**
> >
> > Even if things appear to work with unmigrated apps depending on
> >     migrated apps, Django may not generate all the necessary foreign key
> >     constraints!

In this specific case is seems that the `registration` app has a dependency on the user model. You need to upgrade this app to a version that has the necessary migration files to support Django 1.7+.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, buddy! In my case it was `django-registration-redux==1.1`. Updated it to 1.2 and everything works now!